# How do I successfully run Pester Unit tests locally on a cloned GitHub repo?

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, github, visual-studio-code, pester

I would like to run all Pester Unit tests locally for a project before pushing my changes back up to GitHub and initializing a Pull Request.

So far I've cloned a project, [xFailOverCluster](https://github.com/dsccommunity/xFailOverCluster), and installed `Pester` and all dependent modules (found using the build-script).

- Pester 5.3.1
- `.\build.ps1 -Tasks build`

  - Sampler.GitHubTasks
  - Saved DscResources.Common to \output\RequiredModules
- `.\build.ps1`

  - DscResource.Test

    - DscResource.Analyzer
    - DscxDSCResourceDesigner
    - PSPKI
- DscResources.Common

I can successfully build the module, using the provided `.\build.ps1` script. But the provided Pester Unit tests will all fail.

And when using the more generic `Pester Test Explorer` extension in `VS Code`, I get the same kind of failures:

`Starting discovery in 7 files.`
`[-] Discovery in D:\UsbRepos\One\xFailOverCluster.GitHub\tests\Unit\MSFT_xCluster.Tests.ps1 failed with: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module 'xFailOverCluster' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.`
`...`
`Discovery found 0 tests in 643ms.`
`...`

Comment: Ok, so I got to thinking the `DscResources.Common` is also a module and installed that and then deleted the folder I created earlier...

Comment: The best place to ask is on the issues page of the GitHub repo you cloned it from. The authors and existing contributors of the project are the most qualified to help you.

Comment: Yes, but surely this is a more generic issue? The VS Code Extension is only looking for available Unit tests and don't care about build scripts...

Comment: Try using Pester 4.10.1 instead.  There were some breaking changes in v5 that may be causing this for you.

Comment: The `Pester Tester Extension` requires Pester 5.x but the build uses Pester 4.x. So that's probably why the extension is failing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out it was the build that was at fault on my end (and wrong version of Pester, v4 needed).

Once all dependency modules was in place, I was able to run the Pester tests as invoked by the `build.ps1`.
No way of just running `Invoke-Pester` though in this project.

Comment: I downloaded and did the build and was able to run `Invoke-Pester` just fine from the Tests folder, using Pester v4.10.1 as mentioned in the comments.  Version 5 does not work I believe because code needs to be placed explicitly in BeforeEach/BeforeAll blocks whereas in older version this was not necessary.

Comment: Ah, you moved to the Tests folder first :)

Comment: Didn't work. I'm still missing something that needs to be done to my local repo... `The specified module 'xFailOverCluster' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory`. Do I need to register a PS Repo for the output folder?

Comment: Something strange, seems that `.\build.ps1 -Tasks build` needs to be run first in each powershell session for Invoke-Pester to work.  If I close powershell and open again it build needs to happen again first

Comment: Ok, so definitely a build thing? Perhaps better to move this discussion to [GitHub - Running Pester Unit tests locally before Pull Request #262](https://github.com/dsccommunity/xFailOverCluster/issues/262)?